# How I will get particular value of key in this below output line in Qt?

Tags: json, qt

here is my code.

```
QJsonObject distance = QJsonDocument::fromJson(databuffer).object();
qDebug()<<distance["feeds"];
```

now my output is:

```
QJsonValue(array, QJsonArray([{"created_at":"2021-12-06T06:11:23Z","entry_id":21,"field1":"202"}]))
```

i need only the value of particular **"field1"** key's value.
how can i get it ? please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `distance.value("feeds").toArray().at(0).toObject().value("field1")`.

Of course you should add some error handling in case the data is not in the form as expected. But you probably want to make it more general based on your use case...

And a little explanation: `QJsonValue` is a general value holder and before actual use it should be converted to actual value (`int`, `double`, `QString`, `bool` etc.) or a to container `QJsonArray`, which can be read with position index, or object `QJsonObject`, which can be read by field names.